# Single entity "mapped to the same rows"

Tags: entity-framework, ef-database-first

I saw this error:

> System.Data.EntityCommandCompilationException: An error occurred while
>   preparing the command definition. See the inner exception for details.
>   ---> System.Data.MappingException:   SQL.Data.msl(945,10) : error 3032: Problem in mapping fragments starting at lines 945,
>   965:EntityTypes DIDataModel.TitleEstate are being mapped to the same
>   rows in table TitleEstate. Mapping conditions can be used to
>   distinguish the rows that these types are mapped to.

The grammar seemed odd, using "EntityTypes" plural, and "are" after a one-item list.

How to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

It started working after a clean-and-rebuild, but that was only a temporary fix.

The permanent solution was (as is often the case with Entity Framework problems) to delete the entity from the .edmx diagram and add it back in again.

Comment: For me, this happened after updating the Model from the database. I guess it wasn't smart enough to refresh the entities correctly, but removing them all and updating an empty .edmx worked for me.